# iptables: how to present "not equal to/match" when use -m u32 function

Tags: iptables, firewall

In iptables, -m u32 --u32 can be used to match certain bytes in the packet against user-defined value. For example,

**iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1000 -m u32 --u32 "xxxxxxxxxxx=0x11" -j REJECT**

Through the above iptables rule, the packet will be rejected if the value of certain 1 byte is **equal to** 0x11.

My question is: how to present "**not equal to**" or **"not match"**? From the man page of iptables, it seems there is no such !-m or -m! function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-m u32` portion of the command line specifies the module. The `--u32` portion specifies the actual expression. So, the syntax you are looking for is:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1000 -m u32 ! --u32 "xxxxxxxxxxx=0x11" -j REJECT
```

See also the [iptables-extensions man pages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/iptables-extensions.8.html), excerpt below:

```
 u32
       U32 tests whether quantities of up to 4 bytes extracted from a
       packet have specified values. The specification of what to
       extract is general enough to find data at given offsets from
       tcp headers or payloads.

       [!] --u32 tests
              The argument amounts to a program in a small language described below.
```